# Drupal Views Date Views - Today in History (month, day)

Tags: views, datetime

I am using Drupal 7, Views, Date Views, and Date module.
My database uses a field named "release date" which contains the date that specific items were released (Month/Day/Year)
I would like to customize my view to show only content with today's date (historically) basically showing all items that were released on this Month/Day in a block so that every day new content is displayed. 
Can someone lead me in the right direction to accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add to your view a **contextual filter**: add your date field and select "**Provide default value: current date**". Then, in Granularity (in the same field settings, lower), **set the granularity to a "Day"** so that only content that was marked for that day is displayed.